# Are cookies shared between Safari and Webviews?

Tags: cookies, safari, webview

According to Apple documentation on [NSHTTPCookieStorage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Concepts/URLOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001834-BAJEAIEE)

The NSHTTPCookieStorage class provides the interface for managing the collection of NSHTTPCookie objects shared by all applications.

Therefore, If I'm not mistaken, since a Webview on OS X uses NSHTTPCookieStorage, and Safari uses Webviews, if I login on a given website on a Webview, Safari will use the cookies that has been set by the Webview and when the same website is opened by Safari, it should be authenticated.

My question is, if cookies are shared between Safari and Webviews. If so, why the test above is not working ?

Answer (score 7):

According to the NSHTTPCookieStorage documentation:

> Starting in OS X 10.11, each app has its own sharedHTTPCookieStorage
>   singleton, which will not be shared with other applications.

So while the previous answer was correct 3 years ago when it was written, the answer now should be:

1) before OS X 10.11 - Yes they were shared

2) OS X 10.11 and macOS 10.12 - No they are no longer shared.

Answer (score 5):

Per discussion at [Understanding NSHTTPCookieStorage for the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520331/understanding-nshttpcookiestorage-for-the-iphone), cookies are not shared between applications.

This is confirmed in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Concepts/URLOverview.html) under the "Cookie Storage" section:

> **iOS Note:** Cookies are not shared by applications in iOS.

Comment: Well, in his question, he does say "on OS X", which oddly enough, is not iOS.  ;-)

Comment: @Inafziger Why you have to say this, what's the point ? It's long gone the time when people answered only the question for the OP.  


I come from a google search and was looking for an answer for iOS, so thank you Jeff !

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, on OS X, the answer is a resounding **yes**. Cookies do appear to be shared between Safari and WebViews.

Comment: IMPORTANT: See my answer below.