# How to pass information from the browser to an application? (Ios)

Tags: android, ios, cookies, deep-linking, appsflyer

An example of an AppsFlyer link would be https://app.appsflyer.com/id111111111?pid=my_pid&c=campaign1

this link redirects to the AppStore.
When we launch / install the app, we have the information inside the (Ios) app.

I thought that maybe some cookies are stored by the browser, and then retrieved inside the app. But in my researches I found that it is impossible to share cookies between applications (Web browser and my app).

[Understanding NSHTTPCookieStorage for the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520331/understanding-nshttpcookiestorage-for-the-iphone)

Could someone list me the possibilities for doing that?

1) Cookies?

2) External storage?

And in android? how would this be done?

Another related question:
Does anyone knows how to use AppsFlyer push/pull API?

https://support.appsflyer.com/entries/23655166-Pull-APIs-Pulling-AppsFlyer-Reports-by-APIs

Thanks a lot

Comment: Look into deep links which were introduced in iOS 9

Comment: hey @dstudeba thanks for the answer, but AppsFlyer exists before ios9, doesn't it?

Comment: Sorry, read your question wrong.  Thought you were asking how to pass data not how it is done through Apps Flyer.

Answer (score 2):

AppsFlyer pass the information to the app using a specific http call.

When a user press on the link the parameters are saved on Appsflyer's servers and the user is redirected to the specific app page on the app store, once the user install the app (with the Appsflyer's SDK) and launch it, the circle is closed and attribution is made.

The Attribution/conversion data is passed to the app via the SDK, cookies are not involved in this case.

Comment: Hey, i'm having the same question.I dont understand how "once the user installs the app..." how does appsflyer know, if it already sent the info to the server? How the info comes to the app?

Comment: Hi @Upsilon42 he said "by using a specific http call" but could you please give more information about that specific http call? what do you mean?

Comment: @wp42 There is http call inside the SDK for getting the attribution data, AppsFlyer have a proprietary algorithm which knows to how connects the url click & app install in real time and returning it back to the SDK.